# Bad value for range when using a controller helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller, helper

I'm trying to run a helper method through my ActionController as seen below.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def set_count(object_count, class_name)
    ["new", "create"].include? action_name ? object_count = class_name.count + 1 : object_count = class_name.count
    end
end
```

When I request the new action of that controller I get the error "bad value for range".

```
# app/views/subjects/new.html.erb

<%= form_for @subject do |f| %>
  <table summary="Subject form field">
    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label :position %></th>
        <td><%= f.select :position, 1..@subject_count %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Keep in mind this method works if I place it in the controller itself:

```
# app/controllers/subjects.rb

def set_count
  ["new", "create"].include? action_name ? @subject_count = Subject.count + 1 : @subject_count = Subject.count
end
```

and run it as follows:

`before_action :set_count, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]`

I'd much rather have it as a helper because a couple other controllers use something similar to this. I tried converting the range to a Fixnum using `to_i` but all I get is a select box with no numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
["new", "create"].include?(action_name) ? object_count = class_name.count + 1 : object_count = class_name.count
```

Those brackets are very much needed here. Otherwise ruby parser will interpret it as:

```
["new", "create"].include? (action_name ? object_count = class_name.count + 1 : object_count = class_name.count)
```

Which will return `true` or `false`. (Well, always `false`)

Also, you cannot modify fixnum value passed to the method:

```
def set_count(object_count, class_name)
  ["new", "create"].include? action_name ? object_count = class_name.count + 1 : object_count = class_name.count
end
```

`object_count` is a local variable here, and Fixnum is not a mutable object, hence it will not modify passed param as you would probably expect. This method should read:

```
def get_count(klass)
  ["new", "create"].include?(action_name) ? klass.count + 1 : klass.count
end
```

And then in your view:

```
<td><%= f.select :position, 1..get_count(Subject) %></td>
```

Remember that this method needs to be moved to a helper module, or needs to be marked as a helper method:

```
class SomeController < AplicationController
  helper_method: :get_count
end
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the parenthesis did anything. Still getting that error.

Comment: For some reason when using your `get_count` method and code for the view I'm getting `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` Should I be using both `set_count` and `get_count`?

Comment: Okay I think I might've solved the above. It was a matter of moving the method out of my `ApplicationController` file and over to `ApplicationHelper`. Also removed the before_action since its no longer needed. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind mentioning to move the `get_count` method to the ApplicationHelper in your answer so I can mark this correct? I'll update my question to indicate where the code originally was. It might confuse anyone else looking at this at first glance.

Comment: I would have another look into a problem. There is a chance `get_count` method is now defined twice in different helper modules.

Comment: Not anymore. I ended up putting it in my `ApplicationHelper` controller and removed all the other code which got it to work. If you could just mention placing the `get_account` method in ApplicationHelper instead of the ApplicationController file I'll mark it correct. Since your new code isn't using  instance variables anymore I don't necessarily need it there anymore.